# How to create liquid carbon, and what kinds of properties does it have?

Tags: melting-point, sublimation

Carbon sublimes at about 3915K. In a high pressure environment, shouldn't it be possible to create liquid carbon at high temperatures? Has this ever been done? What does it look like and what properties does it have?

Comment: "What properties does it have?" is unfortunately too broad. Could you be more specific?

Comment: http://news.discovery.com/space/alien-life-exoplanets/diamond-oceans-jupiter-uranus1.htm

Comment: Apparently the melting point of diamond at 11,000,000 atm is only 50,000 &deg; F.  And under those conditions, liquid diamond is more dense than solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to create liquid carbon, but it's extremely hard. As you can see on the Carbon phase diagram  if you want to obtain "easely" liquid carbon you must do it at $\ce{1 GPa}$ and $\ce{5000 K}$.[image: Carbon phase diagram]

And for the properties I really don't know but carbon follows the octet rule and it might be very reactive as an electrophile because it will just have four electrons around it.

I hope it can help you a bit, i'm seeking in some data-bases but there are not really things to answer your question.

Have a nice day.

Comment: It won't be monoatomic

Comment: Yes that what I'm thinking. I will add some hypothesis in my answer when i will have time. I will correct the thing which can mislead.